# dotConnect or "sqlite.phxsoftware.com" for using Entity Framework with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-4, dotconnect, phxsoftware

Which is the better choice out of [dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/) or "[sqlite.phxsoftware.com](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)" for using Entity Framework with SQLite (in C#)?

Comment: arrr...I see with dotConnect the version that supports EF costs $$$

Answer (score 3):

My experience with DotConnect is using DotConnect for Oracle over the past three months.  I cannot comment specifically on DotConnect for SQLLite, however I assume the quality would be similar.

I have not seen any difference between this provider and the provider supplied by Microsoft.   The one exception was when VS 2010 was released, it took Devart a couple of days to release an updated version of dotconnect.  They had promised the new version would be availble within a week and they delivered it in two days.   They also emailed me with a download link.  They are responsive to emails and their forums are helpful.   Hope this helps in making your decision.

Answer (score 3):

System.Data.SQLite works quite well with EF.

I speak from a lot of experience with this scenario.

System.Data.SQLite is and will always be free, whereas dotconnect is bait and switch on features.

HTH

Comment: it seems like it supports the Database => Entity generation flow, but not the Entity => create database schema for a Sqlite database - is this your experience code poet?

Comment: @Greg - yes, the current version was developed before vs10, so model first is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with dotConnect but successfully using System.Data.SQLite (sqlite.phxsoftware.com) during past 3 years in several projects.

If there are choice I prefer open source components/libs so if there are any trouble I can fast troubleshoot it myself without rely on vendor's support and often waiting while they prepare new realease with bugfix.

Check [System.Data.SQLite SF page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/) for some reviews.

Comment: thanks - I'll think I go with you - not sure to do with the question - guess I should lead it open as noone has really answered it in it's current form yet